# Is using Google Plus to answer questions allowable?

Tags: discussion, google+

Is using Google Plus to answer questions allowable? By this I mean, can I click the "Share" button and find someone on G+ to answer the question and then go to Ask Ubuntu (or any other SE site) and answer the question. Just in case my question is unclear, I will give an example.

Can I go to a question like ([mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256866/mmc0-error-110-whilst-initialising-sd-card)) and click "share" and on G+ ask, "Does anyone have an idea?". Then, once I get an answer, can I post on Ask Ubuntu, "Joe Smith from G+ {if I get the user's permission to mention their name} said the problem is with X, so do Y to fix it.".

I have done this a few times (maybe three times), but then I wondered if it is allowable and if it is still fine to do frequently. I do not like seeing answered question. Is this acceptable with questions offering bounties?

Comment: There's 100k+ people in the ubuntu g+ group, us it to your advantage!

Comment: Well, this was said to me by some of the mods a few posts ago: This site is a private site, and all the questions and answers belong to this site (a kind of intellectual property, I reckon), and of course there is no freedom of speech. So I do not know how this sharing questions, getting the answer from another site (which might be an intellectual property of that site), fit in to this whole diagram of confusing facts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the Share buttons says:

> Know **someone who can answer**? **Share** a link to this question via email, Google+, Twitter, or Facebook.

So, we are encouraging that you share the link around to get people to answer the question and if they like create an account (they will get a temporary account cookie based).

Answer (score 5):

I want to add to what Braiam has said. Stack Exchange has the following badges as reward for sharing a link with your networks:

1. [Announcer](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/57/announcer) (Bronze):
   *Shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses.*
2. [Booster](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/58/booster) (Silver):
   *Shared a link to a question that was visited by 300 unique IP addresses.*
3. [Publicist](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/59/publicist) (Gold):
   *Shared a link to a question that was visited by 1000 unique IP addresses.*

If you are after more information those badges are specified on the [badges](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges) section.